# Using python to write a daemon instead of C++

Tags: python, linux, daemon

I am about to start into a daemon project with a friend, he will do the design and I will do the coding
I am confused between Python and C++
I know C++, but I need to learn Python if I will go with it
The daemon I am about to write will be more than 1 daemon actually, each one is responsible for a function, such as accepting ***SSL*** connections from network, stream audio and video, sending files and data and more network operations, I like going with C++ but I am afraid from the time I'll lose fixing the memory leaks that will occur (for sure), but also I am afraid from Python because I don't know it and I don't know if it can do the job for me or not

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the right tools in C++. shared_ptr<>, e.g. lets you avoid most hairy memory leak situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right tool for the right job. If you want a process that keeps on running for a long time you will want a proof of some of it's correctness (not a complete one, but at least something). This proof is given to you by the compiler or interpreter accepting the language. It depends a lot on the language, what kind of things are proven about your program. For python you get a proof of syntactic correctness, that is all. If you use C++ existence of all methods and some type soundness will also be proven. This is much better for long running processes, such as daemon. There are languages, where you can use the compiler to prove even more, but this is often not as simple.

Don't worry too much about the memory leaks. As has been pointed out in the comments, if you use modern C++ memory leaks or memory corruption are not an issue anymore and speed will be much higher, than if a garbage collector is present. Use C++ or C++0x but not C/C++, and all will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't know whats wrong with this Q, so people did not like it, this is just like any other question can be asked